# Alterar src do link da imagem

Tags: jquery

Tenho várias imagens em listas,

http://www.shopluxo.com.br/arquivos/ids/177260-**150-150**/212-Vip---brinde.jpg

Gostaria de alterar de todas apenas o **150-150** para 200-200.

Consigo alterar apenas de uma.

Comment: Código que tens feito?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assumindo que não haja a possibilidade dessa expressão **150-150** se repetir em nenhuma parte do URL, seria algo assim:

```
$( document ).ready( fucntion() {

    $( 'ul#something li img' ).each( function() {

        var path = $( this ).attr( 'src' );

        $( this ).attr( 'src', path.replace( '150-150', '200-200' ) );

    });
});
```

Define o seltor, itera e para cada imagem encontrada você obtém o *path*, fas a substituição e os redefine.

Comment: Muito obrigado Bruno

Comment: Que bom que funcionou, porque eu nem testei >.<

Answer (score 1):

Não testei, mas considerando 'imagem' sendo o link que você passou, isso provavelmente funciona:

```
imagem = imagem.replace("150-150", "200-200");
```